# MongoMemoryServer + mocha: individual test pass but toghetehr they fail

Tags: mocha.js, mongo-memory-server

Im making sure duplicates aren't added to my collection.

The tests looks like this:

```
context("createTransaction", ()=>{
        it("Create a new transaction from a TransactionType-format that and add it to the db",async ()=>{
            const before=await db.countTrans();
            const result=await createTransaction(jsonTrans);
            const after=await db.countTrans();
            assert.equal(before+1,after)
        });
    })
        it("Add a duplicate, expect an error",async ()=>{
            await db.addTransaction(jsonTrans)
            const before=await db.countTrans();
            const result=await createTransaction(jsonTrans);
            const after=await db.countTrans();
            assert.equal(before,after);
            assert.equal(11000,result.code);
        });
```

I have a testDb file that handles the connection to the mocked db:

```
const mongod = MongoMemoryServer.create();
before(async () => {
    await connect();
});
after(async () => {
    await closeDatabase();
});
afterEach(async()=>{
    await reset();
})

export const connect = async () => {
    const uri = await (await mongod).getUri();
    await mongoose.connect(uri);
}
export const closeDatabase = async () => {
    await mongoose.connection.dropDatabase();
    await mongoose.connection.close();
    await (await mongod).stop();
}
export const reset=async ()=> {
    if(await category.collection.countDocuments()>0){
        await category.collection.drop();
    }
    if(await Transaction.collection.countDocuments()>0){
        await Transaction.collection.drop();
    }
}
```

and finally the transaction model:

```
const TransactionSchema: Schema = new Schema(
    {
        RegisterDate: { type: String, require: true },
        TransactionDate: { type: String, require: true },
        Name: { type: String, require: true },
        Description: { type: String, require: true },
        Amount: { type: String, require: true },
        Balance: { type: String, require: true },
        Category: { type: String, require: true },
    },
    {
        versionKey: false,
        collection: "Transactions",
    }
);
TransactionSchema.index(
    {
        RegisterDate: 1,
        TransactionDate: 1,
        Name: 1,
        Description: 1,
        Amount: 1,
        Balance: 1,
    },
    { unique: true }
);
```

The problem as stated is that both these tests pass without problem when run individually. But not as a suite.

Now, this is what (I think) I've found out so far:

- The tests are executed sequentially so race condition shouldnt be an issue.
- The collection is indeed empty by the time we enter the test block
- Adding a duplicate returns the error code 11000 as expected when the test is run individually,  but is added to the collection without error when run toghether.
- Changing the order of the tests makes them pass toghether.

As you see I have a workaround, but I just dont understand why I need it. I have a theory that somehow I'm disabling the model and therefore the check for duplicates but I dont understand it.

Anyone can shed some light into this?